# Array to span multiple views/tables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I’m using Swift and Xcode 6.1. I have a form built in IB that contains a TableView which is fed by an Array. I am using a system that just captures the view and
turns it in to a PDF file :-

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil)   
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()     
self.view.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

The code works fine for just 1 set of values from the array that don’t exceed the first table size but I need to captures each table
with the array values.

Imagine a invoice that has page numbers and an unknown amount of lines.

I’ve set the row limit to 10 but just can’t figure a way to do a capture sequence, i.e :-

1. Display array values 0 > 9
2. Capture view
3. refresh table
4. Display array values 10 > 19
   5  Capture view
5. Refresh table
6. Display array values 20 > 24
7. Capture view
8. Write multi-page PDF - `pdfData.writeToFile(documentDirectoryFilename, atomically: true)`

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1stlw9gu44f7iyx/shot.png?raw=1

The table is being driven from just the standard :-

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as OrderFormCell

         var data = Orders[indexPath.row]


        let netFloat = data.valueForKey("net") as Float
        cell.netPriceLabel.text = NSString(format: "£%.2f", netFloat)

        cell.bookOrderLabel.text = data.valueForKey("book") as String?
        cell.bookOrderLabel.sizeToFit()
        cell.isbnLabel.text = data.valueForKey("isbn") as String?

        // ----- Int to String -------------------
        let quantityAsInt : Int = data.valueForKey("quantity") as Int!
        cell.quantityLabel.text = "\(quantityAsInt)"


        // -------- NString to Float -------------
        let bb : NSString = cell.quantityLabel.text!

        bookValue  = data.valueForKey("booktotal") as Float
        cell.bookNetValueOutlet.text = NSString(format: "£%.2f", bookValue)

        totalValueOutlet.text = NSString(format: "£%.2f", totalValue)

        return cell

    }
```

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Once you capture an image, change which array feeds the table, and call reloadData.

Comment: Could you post your tableview delegate methods?

Comment: added the viewable code

Comment: There is only 1 array. Are you suggesting that i split the array into pieces?

Comment: @NickHawkes I'd definitely recommend populating your table's data source array with just the current table content and I'd also recommend setting numberOfRowsInSection to return that current array count...not a static number.

Comment: the reason i set the numberOfRowsInSection to 10 is so I could control the amount of entries per page. I've not seen any example anywhere of anyone being able to do this so I may give up.